# All Page Cache (FPC) Invalidated When Saving Any Product

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, magento2.3.2

I am trying to work out why page cache is invalidated/cleared whenever a product is opened and saved.

The expected behaviour: would be that if you edit product A all product pages and categories that product A shows on would be invalidated.

What is actually happening: Editing any product clears ALL pages cache.

What I have tried?
Disabling modules, this has not made any difference.
Disabling cronjobs. seems to improve the situation but is not a proper fix. Has anyone else had this and have any ideas what is causing it?

EDIT: By disabling and enabling all Cron Jobs I have narrowed it down to

indexer_update_all_views / Magento\Indexer\Cron\UpdateMview

as soon as this is enabled it starts clearing ALL page cache as soon as a product is saved.

Currently, its schedule is * * * * * , would there be any harm in setting it to a much longer time span?

EDIT 2: After a huge amount of digging it appears that we are not the only ones seeing this,

See these github tickets:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25670
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4688

Answer (score 0):

I think it is by design! There's bug open on it but it doesn't seem to be getting any attention (tell all your friends!): https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25670#issuecomment-576369670